# Viewmodel and LINQ query to represent 4 linked tables in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, viewmodel

I'm using a typical invoice system as a test for developing MVC and ViewModel knowledge, before tackling migrating my employers inhouse systems from asp to asp.net MVC.

I know ViewModels are the recommended way to display info in the view - so I was hoping for some help "flattening" the viewmodel for the following:

tables: Invoice, InvoiceItem, Payment, PaymentInvoice

Invoice and InvoiceItem are linked, and Payment (which records an overall payment), and PaymentInvoice (which lists which invoices the Payment covers) are also linked.

I would like a ViewModel to show me:

InvoiceId
CustomerName
Total of Invoice (quantity X UnitPrice plus VAT)
AmountAllocated (from the PaymentInvoice table)
Outstanding (TotalofInvoice - AmountAllocated)

So I think my ViewModel should be:

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    public Int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalofInvoice { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountAllocated { get; set; }
    public decimal Outstanding { get; set; }
}
```

My domain models are:

```
public class Invoice
{

    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvDate { get; set; }
    public IList<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceItem
{
    public int InvoiceItemId { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal VAT { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

    // calculated fields
    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return Quantity * UnitPrice; }
    }
    public decimal VATAmount
    {
        get { return TotalPlusVAT - Total; }
    }
    public decimal TotalPlusVAT
    {
        get { return Total * (1 + VAT / 100); }
    }
}

public class Payment
{
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateReceived { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalReceived { get; set; }
    public IList<PaymentInvoice> PaymentInvoices { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentInvoice
{
    public int PaymentInvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountAllocated { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Payment Payment { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is in how to link the Payment and PaymentInvoice table to the Invoice and InvoiceItem table, so I can use a LINQ query in my controller to populate the viewmodel with the "flattened data".

I'm lost with the LINQ query too - in LinqPad I've got:

```
from c in Invoices
join i in InvoiceItems on c.InvoiceId equals i.InvoiceId
join pi in PaymentInvoices on c.InvoiceId equals pi.InvoiceId
select new {...into ViewModel????...}
```

...but not sure where to go after that.

**EDIT** - The closest I've got is the Sql to do this is:

```
SELECT     Invoices.InvoiceId, 
           Invoices.CustomerName, 
           (SUM(InvoiceItems.Quantity * InvoiceItems.UnitPrice)) AS TotalOfInvoice, 
           (SELECT     SUM(AmountAllocated) AS Expr1
                          FROM         PaymentInvoices
                          WHERE     (InvoiceId = Invoices.InvoiceId)) AS AmountAllocated, 
           SUM(InvoiceItems.Quantity * InvoiceItems.UnitPrice) 
           - (SELECT     SUM(AmountAllocated) AS Expr1
                          FROM         PaymentInvoices
                          WHERE     (InvoiceId = Invoices.InvoiceId)) AS Outstanding
FROM         Invoices LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  InvoiceItems ON Invoices.InvoiceId = InvoiceItems.InvoiceId
GROUP BY Invoices.InvoiceId, Invoices.CustomerName
```

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: The difference between your SQL and the LINQ query is "INNER JOIN" vs "LEFT OUTER JOIN". Do some Google searches on "LINQ left outer join" to get some examples, like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

Comment: Thanks - using that, I've got it showing individual items, but I'm looking to sum items in the query - what I have now is: var invs = from invoice in Invoices
                       join item in InvoiceItems on invoice.InvoiceId equals item.InvoiceId into gj
        from subitem in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {invoice.CustomerName, costs=(subitem == null ? 0:subitem.UnitPrice)
        }; (just trying one link just now, to see if I can get it working)

Answer (score 2):

I think your Linq query is almost perfect you just need to select new ViewModels:

```
from c in Invoices
join i in InvoiceItems on c.InvoiceId equals i.InvoiceId
join pi in PaymentInvoices on c.InvoiceId equals pi.InvoiceId
select new InvoiceViewModel {
    InvoiceId = c.InvoiceId,
    CustomerName = c.CustomerName,
    TotalofInvoice = c.InvoiceItems.Sum(invoiceitem => invoiceitem.Total(),
    AmountAllocated = ...
    Outstanding = ...
};
```

Comment: Hi @Kenneth - thanks - I guessed I was on the right track, but I'm not getting anywhere - I've posted the working SQL statement - I'm wondering if anyone can help expand on my Linq/Kenneths Linq to show how the statement should be converted to work in LINQ?  Thank you, Mark